# Python list and range

Tags: python

Could you tell me how I can write  a working code if I don't know how many items the list contains (without using the len function, so I want a code that simply ignores the rest of the range if it is longer than the list).   e.g. this code only works with the given range and not range (0,10)

```
   gfgf=[[1],[2]]
        for i in range (0,1):
            if 1 in gfgf[i] :
                print (gfgf)
```

Also could you tell me what we call the components of a list ([1] and [2] of gfgf in the example). We call the components of a dictionary 'items '.

Comment: You can call the components elements, though it's not really that important. I think programmers will understand what you mean if you called them items.

Comment: What is the expected output in this program? Can you add a few examples? Right now it's kinda hard to understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gfgf=[[1],[2]]
for x in gfgf:
    if 1 in x:
        print(x)
```

You can simply just do `for x in mylist`

Comment: And if he'd like the index, too, `for idx, x in enumerate(gfgf):`

Answer (score 0):

I would write that function this way:

```
gfgf=[[1],[2]]
for i in gfgf:
    if 1 in i:
        print(gfgf)
```

Hope this helps!